# creating polyline and polygon on Google map and how to store in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I am trying to create polyline and polygon on google map but i m not getting how to do that and also wants to store cordinates into database. Please tell me the idea or is there any example or tutorial present,please guide me i m making a small app and i m stuck in this problem your help will be appriciated thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please share the work you've done so far and what you've researched to get to where you are today.  As it currently is, your question will likely be put on hold/closed for being too broad.

Comment: Google provide plenty documentation and examples, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes